# Widget's container?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets, sidebar

I have some custom-made widgets:

```
echo $before_widget;
   if ( $title )
      echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
echo $output;
echo $after_widget;
```

Let's assume the $title is "Widget's Title" and the output is "Hello world".

I'm getting something like:

> Widget's Title
>
> Hello world

Now, I don't know where it comes, but there's container wrapping every one of my widgets, it looks like:

```
<li id="widgets-id" class="widget widget_name">
   <h3>$title</h3>
      <ul>
         <li>$output</li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Any ideas how to change the first "li" into "section" or a "div"? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the default behavior of a dynamic sidebar to output li tags around widgets. You can [override that though in the sidebar declaration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Register_Single_Sidebar).

You would do that by passing the sidebar registration the following additional arguments:

```
register_sidebar(
  array(
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</div>"
  )
);
```